# Is there a CSS selector engine written in C?

Tags: css, c, css-selectors

I'm looking for examples of open-source [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) engines written in C.

As an example of what I'm looking for, [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) or [Peppy](http://jamesdonaghue.com/static/peppy/) are JavaScript implementations, and [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) is a C# implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [LibCSS](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/libcss/) and [libcroco](https://launchpad.net/libcroco).